# How do I get npm to display output in PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

When I run any npm command such as npm -v or npm install, there is no output, nor does the terminal pause to indicate some kind of processing. It just returns to input.
However, when I do the same in another terminal such as Git Bash, an output is displayed. I have a preference for PowerShell on Windows and would like it to work there instead.

Comment: Not solving your problem but try using VS Code terminal. I find it most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run PowerShell as administrator.